# allergen web api

Tags: web-services, web-applications

Does anyone know of an API that publishes current allergen levels?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get access to the [AccuWeather API](http://www.accuweather.com/api.asp) which should offer access to their allergen level values by zip code.